# How to display value got from API into ReactJS page

Tags: reactjs, api

let `resultofapi` is declared globally and I initialized it with the value I received from API. I want to display that value to my react js page (inside a table). When I print the value inside the API it returns me output `{"similarity_score":0.9999999404}`.but when I access it outside the API, it gives me value=undefine

```
pd.usage()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })

  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
**pd.semantic(
  pd
    .semantic(textarea1, textarea2)//these are forms data
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response); //output={"similarity_score":0.670276463}
     *resultofapi = response;* //output=resultofapi={"similarity_score":0.670276463}*
    })**
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response); 
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
console.log(resultofapi)//output=undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a state object and setState it with the API Data. From that you can access it allover your class.

```
this.state = {
  items: []
};


componentDidMount() {
fetch("https://url.url.com")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      this.setState({
        items: result.items
      });
    },
    // Note: it's important to handle errors here
    // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
    // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
    (error) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error
      });
    }
  )


return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => (
        <li key={item.name}>
          {item.name} {item.price}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
```